# Can YouTube advertising do target location selection by DMA?

Tags: youtube, google-ads-api, dma

In Google Ads, you can select by (Designated Market Areas (DMA® Regions)), but doing so apparently eliminates any placements of ads on YouTube.

Thus my question: Can YouTube advertising do target location selection by DMA?

Comment: By DMA, you mean (*Designated Market Areas (DMA® Regions)*)? - please [edit] your question and clarify. Also, what is your research about this subject?

Comment: Hi Mauricio,

Thanks for your response, I did make the edit to clarity "DMA".

My research is prompted by all YouTube placements disappearing from our "Where ads showed" list after we started targeting by DMA.  Trying to determine if the two are connected.